# Initialization of 3D global arrays in C

Tags: c

I have global 3D arrays defined as

```
double*** arr;
```

in a file common.c

I have the declaration

```
extern double*** arr;
```

in a file common.h

Now when I am initializing this array dynamically at runtime, I am running into a segmentation fault
I executed the code

```
 exs =malloc(sizeof(double)*nx*ny*nz);
```

where nx,ny and nz are known at runtime prior to executing this statement.

But when i try to initialize this array as

```
  for(i=0;i<nx;i++)  
      for(j=0;j<ny;j++)  
          for(k=0;k<nz;k++)  
              arr[i][j][k]=0.0e0;
```

I get a segfault.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: off-by-one error? your for loops should have `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: You don't have a 3D array, you have a pointer to pointer(s) to pointer(s) to int(s).  You need to malloc at every level.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Corrected the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to allocate *all* dimensions:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * nx);
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * ny);
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(***arr) * nz);
        for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++)
        {
            arr[i][j][k] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

And of course don't forget to free all the data you allocated.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Fortunately I did. :P

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Better say `malloc(sizeof(*arr))` instead of an explicit type, it's safer in case the base type of the pointer changes.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `calloc` to get the zeros right at init time?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, [arrays are not pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Second, let me show you another solution which tries to avoid memory fragmentation and uses one single call to the `malloc()` function (which is expensive):

```
double (*arr)[ny][nz] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * nx);
```

After this, you can use `arr` as an array of dimensions `nx * ny * nz`.

And if you want this to be used at file scope: declare it as `void *`, allocate memory for `nx * ny * nz` elements, then assign it to a pointer-to-array when used for convenience:

```
// common.h
extern void *ptr;

// common.c
ptr = malloc(sizeof(double) * nx * ny * nz);

// foo.c
double (*arr)[ny][nz] = ptr;
```

But if you need such a hack... you should be thinking about what you have done wrong. Well, in this case, you've done wrong one thing: you are using a global variable. **Don't use it.**

Comment: @TaylorFlores Thanks. (I hope also for the one-malloc approach.)

Comment: Looks nicer - too bad that this declaration cannot be global or extern when ny and nz are not constant.

Comment: @Armali Yes, that's why one should declare it as `double *ptr`, then convert it to `double (*)[ny][nz]` at usage-time.

Comment: @Armali But anyway, ***why does OP use a global variable at all?***